# Is credulus a diminutive?

Tags: etymology, diminutive

In the comments to an [answer involving the adjective *credulus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6215/what-is-gullible-in-latin) the question has arisen if this word is to be parsed as a diminutive, even if the form of which it would be a diminutive (say, **credus*, like *fidus*) isn't attested. On the other hand, there are adjectives like *tremulus* and especially [*sedulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sedulus&la=la&can=sedulus0&prior=rubicundulus#lexicon) that don't seem to involve a sense of smallness.

So, is the *-ulus* suffix in *credulus* a trace of a diminutive or not? Is the answer the same for the other adjectives mentioned?

I have seen that there are other questions on apparent diminutives ([*angulus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/is-angulus-a-diminutive), [*oculus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5963/what-is-oculus-a-diminutive-of), [*ulula*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5385/is-ulula-a-diminutive)), but it doesn't seem that the answer to the present question can be extrapolated from those.

Answer (score 7):

According to Gildersleeve and Lodge, §182.1, `‑ulus` is a regular former of adjectives from verbs. This particular formation indicates repeated action. They cite *querulus* and I could add *bibulus*. `‑bundus` is *un*repeated action (*cunctabundus*, *nauseabundus*). `‑bilis` (*amabilis*, *bibibilis*, *vendibilis*) is passive action, as also, I suspect, is `‑ulis` (*edulis*).

The whole section is well worth reading. I used to envy Sanskrit for its systematic approach to verbal adjectives, but Latin, though more chaotic, has nothing to be ashamed of.

And yes, the phonetic coincidence with diminutives can give an "atmosphere" to certain `‑ulus` adjectives – a certain air of condescension – but no more than that.

Comment: Great answer!  So then I guess _credulus_ means gullible because you repeatedly believe something - a sort of "fool me once, shame on you; fool me twice, shame on me" idea.

Answer (score 1):

Even though a non-diminuitive version of `credulus` does not exist, it kind of has this "smallness" connotation. If somebody is `credulus`, he is childish in some way, so you call at least some part of his brain little developed. This naivity comes with a childish innocence and also dinkiness. Furthermore, this is meant derogatively, so there are some fulfilled aspects of a diminuitive which surely caused this ending. However, gramatically it is still no diminuitive as it does not have an non-diminuitive origin.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this sentence: “gramatically it is still no diminuitive as it does not have an non-diminuitive origin.” Could you please check it?

Comment: @DaG Normally, every diminuitive has got a non-diminuitive origin. For example, parvulus is a diminuitive and its origin is parvus. But credulus does not have an origin like that as the word credus does not exist. Therefore, I do not consider this a real diminuitive.